# Get $_POST from PHP to Javascript and pass it to another php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I build a search feature with infinite scroll. How do i get search string from search page to my scroll page for query database.

PHP :

search.php

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/css/scroll.css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/search.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="search">
        <form action="search" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="search" id="search" autocomplete="off">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
        <img id='loading' src='img/loading.gif'>
        <div id="demoajax" cellspacing="0">
        </div>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/infinitescroll/search.js"></script>
```

scroll.php

```
<?php 
include('db.php');

$searchstring = $_POST['search'];

if(isset($_REQUEST['actionfunction']) && $_REQUEST['actionfunction']!=''){ 
     $actionfunction = $_REQUEST['actionfunction'];
     call_user_func($actionfunction,$_REQUEST,$con,$limit);
}
     function showData($data,$con,$limit){
     $page = $data['page'];
     if($page==1){
     $start = 0;
}
else{
    $start = ($page-1)*$limit;
}
    $sql = "SELECT fm_product.p_name, fm_product.p_descp, fm_product.p_id, fm_product.p_price, fm_product.p_discount, fm_product.p_img, fm_member.member_display_name, fm_product.p_member_id, fm_package.package_name, fm_package.package_id FROM fm_member LEFT JOIN fm_product ON fm_member.member_id = fm_product.p_member_id LEFT JOIN fm_package ON fm_member.package_id = fm_package.package_id order by p_created_date desc limit $start,$limit";
$str='';
$data = $con->query($sql);
if($data!=null && $data->num_rows>0) {
    while( $row = $data->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    if($row['package_id']=='1'){
        $package = "No Package";
    } else {
        $package = "<form class='form-item'><input name='product_code' type='hidden' value='".$row['p_id']."'><button type='submit'>Add to Cart</button></input></form>";
    }
    $id = $row['p_id'];
    $str.="<div style=align: center class='data-container'><a href=item?id = $id><img src=upload/".$row['p_img']." width=300px style=max-width:100%; height: auto; vertical-align: middle></a><p>By ".$row['member_display_name']."</p><p>Product Name : ".$row['p_name']."</p><p>Price : ".$row['p_price']."</p><p>Discount : ".$row['p_discount']."</p><p>Description : ".$row['p_descp']."</p><p>Package ".$_POST['search']." : ".$row['package_name']."</p><p>".$package."</p></div>";
    }
    $str.="<input type='hidden' class='nextpage' value='".($page+1)."'><input type='hidden' class='isload' value='true'>";
} else {
  $str .= "<input type='hidden' class='isload' value='false'><p>Finished</p>";
}
echo $str;
} 
?>
```

Javascript :

search.js

```
 var ajax_arry=[];
 var ajax_index =0;
 var sctp = 100;
 $(function(){
   $('#loading').show();
 $.ajax({
     url:"scroll.php",
              type:"POST",
              data:"actionfunction=showData&page=1",
    cache: false,
    success: function(response){
       $('#loading').hide();
      $('#demoajax').html(response);

    }

   });
$(window).scroll(function(){

   var height = $('#demoajax').height();
   var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();
   if(ajax_arry.length>0){
   $('#loading').hide();
   for(var i=0;i<ajax_arry.length;i++){
     ajax_arry[i].abort();
   }
}
   var page = $('#demoajax').find('.nextpage').val();
   var isload = $('#demoajax').find('.isload').val();

     if ((($(window).scrollTop()+document.body.clientHeight)==$(window).height()) && isload=='true'){
       $('#loading').show();
   var ajaxreq = $.ajax({
     url:"scroll.php",
              type:"POST",
              data:"actionfunction=showData&page="+page,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response){
       $('#demoajax').find('.nextpage').remove();
       $('#demoajax').find('.isload').remove();
       $('#loading').hide();

      $('#demoajax').append(response);

    }

   });
   ajax_arry[ajax_index++]= ajaxreq;

   }
return false;

if($(window).scrollTop() == $(window).height()) {
   alert("bottom!");
}
});

});
```

I want to get `$_POST['search']` from `search.php` to `scroll.php` for replace it into `WHERE` on this query like.

```
$sql = "SELECT ... FROM ... LEFT JOIN ... ON ... LEFT JOIN ... ON ... WHERE p_name LIKE '%$_POST['search']' ORDER BY ... LIMIT ..."
```

Appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
<form action="search" method="post">
```

This redirects to `/search` page, which you don't have. You have `/search.php` and `/scroll.php`. I think you should just put `scroll.php` as the action, and you'd get your result.

```
<form action="scroll.php" method="post">
```

EDIT:
I seem to have misunderstood the code. `scroll.php` is an API endpoint in this. Then the action remains `search.php`, BUT, in order to have the submitted values, you can kill 2 birds with 1 stone.

1. Update the form HTML (you don't need action, you don't need the form either, but let's keep it):

   ```
   <form action="" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="search" id="search" autocomplete="off">
       <button type="button" id="do_search" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
   </form>
   ```
2. In your JS, make the function get triggered by the search:

   ```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $("#do_search").on("click", function() {
           var searchTerm = $("#search").val();

           //this is where you do the AJAX stuff. You can use searchTerm variable.
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: I've put `scroll.php` to the action. But when I search, It bring me to `scroll.php` not `search.php` .

Comment: I don't really know what do I should out on `//this is where you do the AJAX stuff. You can use searchTerm variable`. Can you do a example for me?