# Store value from $_POST or PHP variable into Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

**search.php**

```html
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="search" id="search" autocomplete="off">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
</form>
    <?php $search = $_POST['search']; ?> // This is what I've tried.
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/search.js"></script>
```

I've tried to added `$search = $_POST['search'];` and put it into `search.js` like this `var searchTerm = "<?php echo $search; ?>";`

**search.js**

```
 var ajax_arry=[];
 var ajax_index =0;
 var sctp = 100;
 $(function(){
   $('#loading').show();
   var searchTerm = "<?php echo $search; ?>"; // This is what I've tried.
 $.ajax({
     url:"scroll.php",
              type:"POST",
              data:"actionfunction=showData&page=1&search="+searchTerm, // This is what I've tried.
    cache: false,
    success: function(response){
       $('#loading').hide();
      $('#demoajax').html(response);

    }

   });
$(window).scroll(function(){

   var height = $('#demoajax').height();
   var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();
   if(ajax_arry.length>0){
   $('#loading').hide();
   for(var i=0;i<ajax_arry.length;i++){
     ajax_arry[i].abort();
   }
}
   var page = $('#demoajax').find('.nextpage').val();
   var isload = $('#demoajax').find('.isload').val();

     if ((($(window).scrollTop()+document.body.clientHeight)==$(window).height()) && isload=='true'){
       $('#loading').show();
   var ajaxreq = $.ajax({
     url:"scroll.php",
              type:"POST",
              data:"actionfunction=showData&page="+page,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response){
       $('#demoajax').find('.nextpage').remove();
       $('#demoajax').find('.isload').remove();
       $('#loading').hide();

      $('#demoajax').append(response);

    }

   });
   ajax_arry[ajax_index++]= ajaxreq;

   }
return false;

if($(window).scrollTop() == $(window).height()) {
   alert("bottom!");
}
});

});
```

But when I get `search` from `data:"actionfunction=showData&page=1&search="+searchTerm` on `scroll.php` to query it does not work.

```
function showData($data,$con,$limit){
$page = $data['page'];
if($page==1){
    $start = 0;
}
else{
    $start = ($page-1)*$limit;
}
$name = $data['search'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE p_name LIKE '%$name'";
```

Comment: You can't write `php code` inside `.js` file

Comment: try with replace `<?php `$search = $_POST['search'];` ?>` to `<?php $search = $_POST['search']; ?>` and include js in your php file

Comment: Sorry <?php $search = $_POST['search'];` ?>` it just a mistake from posting. I've edited.

Comment: Try to write the js code inside php file and your code will be work

Comment: Are you doing any debugging / testing yourself? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760646/how-to-input-post-from-php-to-another-php-in-javascript-url-function and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34757796/get-post-from-php-to-javascript-and-pass-it-to-another-php seem awful similar to this one, all posted within a small time frame.

Comment: So sorry about that, But it does not have any best answer in my oldest question posted. Actually it's all my mistake that I can't explained my question clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should include your Js code in your php file. Because you can not write php code in js file. while js code can be written in php.

So your code should be like.

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" autocomplete="off">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
</form>

<?php if ($_POST) {
    $search = $_POST['search'];
    ?> 
    <script>
        var ajax_arry = [];
        var ajax_index = 0;
        var sctp = 100;
        $(function () {
            $('#loading').show();
            var searchTerm = "<?php echo $search; ?>"; // This is what I've tried.
            $.ajax({
                url: "scroll.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: "actionfunction=showData&page=1&search=" + searchTerm, // This is what I've tried.
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    $('#demoajax').html(response);

                }

            });
            $(window).scroll(function () {

                var height = $('#demoajax').height();
                var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();
                if (ajax_arry.length > 0) {
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    for (var i = 0; i < ajax_arry.length; i++) {
                        ajax_arry[i].abort();
                    }
                }
                var page = $('#demoajax').find('.nextpage').val();
                var isload = $('#demoajax').find('.isload').val();

                if ((($(window).scrollTop() + document.body.clientHeight) == $(window).height()) && isload == 'true') {
                    $('#loading').show();
                    var ajaxreq = $.ajax({
                        url: "scroll.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: "actionfunction=showData&page=" + page,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (response) {
                            $('#demoajax').find('.nextpage').remove();
                            $('#demoajax').find('.isload').remove();
                            $('#loading').hide();

                            $('#demoajax').append(response);

                        }

                    });
                    ajax_arry[ajax_index++] = ajaxreq;

                }
                return false;

                if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(window).height()) {
                    alert("bottom!");
                }
            });

        });
    </script>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Accepted. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

You do not "store" PHP variables in javascript. PHP is server sided and javascript works on the client side. They have to communicate.

**Solutions**

1. Create a hidden input with php that you can sleect with javascript
   `<input type="hidden" name="Language" value="English" id="val1">`
2. Use `ajax` to make a call in javascript to the php file, make the php file return the desired value
3. use embedded javascript inside the PHP file that will be served to the user. However I would not recommend that.

Comment: I don't know how to do that, Could you please make an example for me?

Comment: @ButterToast which of the 3?